# issue in passing an object from one activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, serialization

I am working on project in which I have to pass object from one activity to another, BUT I am facing this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.****.****.model.Contract)

**FirstActivity**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(ContractActivity.this,"POsition : "+ arg2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (mSeparatorsSet.contains(arg2))
                    return;
                Contract history = contractsListOrg.get(arg2);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ContractActivity.this, ContractDetailActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("contract", history);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

**Modal Class**

```
public class Contract implements Serializable {
    private int is_cancelled;
    private String status;

 public int getIs_cancelled() {
        return is_cancelled;
    }

    public void setIs_cancelled(int is_cancelled) {
        this.is_cancelled = is_cancelled;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

**Second Activity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contract_detail);
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        changeActionBarLookAndFeel();


        initialization();
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("contract")) {
            history = (Contract) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("contract");
            setValues(history);
        }
    }
```

I have googled most of the answers are telling me to implement `Serializable` on modal class which I already did. anyone tell me what is wrong here ? or is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to implement Parcelable instead, it works faster on Android OS.
You can use auto generation for this. 
Simply add Parcelable Plugin in Android Studio.

Then, in Method generations will be available option Parcelable.

Comment: it isn't possible with Serializable ?

Comment: It is possible, usually this problem occurs when some of inner fields do not implement Serializable. Try adding an empty public constructor

Answer (score 0):

base on what you want to pass to another class you can use Intent or Bundle or Even use an Interface...

Intent and Bundle are suitable for passing variables or objects from an activity to another activity.

if you want get an variable in non-activity class or etc... you better use interface.

in this case you are getting input/output exception which means your input variable is not get to your class,i didnt see your some methods and what they are doing but i think you should check your `if` condition or check to call your methods sooner in upper line